# how to enable Visor Command Line In Apache Ignite?

Tags: datagrid, ignite, in-memory-database, gridgain

I have started Apache Ignite server via Maven Dependency trough eclipse,can anyone tell me how to monitor cache through visor command? How to enable it when setup Apache Ignite via Maven?

Comment: Not sure about Visor, but have you had a chance to take a look at the free Web Console management tool, hosted by GridGain? You can use it to manage and configure your Ignite clusters. Here is the link: https://console.gridgain.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the most easy way is to download [binary distributive](https://ignite.apache.org/download.cgi#binaries) and lunch Visor command line from "\bin" folder. Note, you need to download release that match to that you are using in your Maven based application.

The second way is to use ignite-visor-console [module from Maven](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cignite-visor-console)

And start Visor command line via: org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole object (it extends App). Note, Visor command line is written on Scala.

Sample code:

```
import org.apache.ignite.visor.commands.VisorConsole;

public class Test {
    static public void main(String args[]) {
        VisorConsole.main(args);
    }
}
```

Also see Visor command line [documentation](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/command-line-interface).

And also give a try for Web Console, as Dmitriy suggested.

Comment: as per your suggestion I have add ignite-visor-console dependency in pom.xml but what next? How to start monitoring?

Comment: @SambhajiSawant, I updated my answer with sample code.

Comment: It Started successfully but when I enter open command following error occur